# Lock screen notifications not useful - how do I change it?

Tags: lock-screens, samsung-touchwiz

The first screenshot is when my locked Samsung Galaxy Note 3 AT&T wakes up when receiving a notification. I'm not too pleased with the lack of information displayed. How can I have it display the content of the notification as well?

[image: when screen is locked]

The second screenshot is when I wave my hand over the air sensor and the screen wakes up showing the status of my device. Same comment here, the content here is mostly useless.

First of all, what is causing the blue lock screen display? Is there a way to disable it (I might have installed another app)? Second, how do I change both screens to show more useful content?

[image: when I wave over the air sensor]

Comment: Has the screen always been like that? Did it appear after you installed an app? There is no way to fully change the lockscreen - lockscreen replacement apps have you disable the main lockscreen. The only way would be with a custom ROM.